# Equivalence between "a iff b" and "(a → b)^(b→a)"

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

so I have gotten a bit lost on this.

"a iff b"

suggests to be that "a" can be the case only if "b" is the case so that having "a" be true and "b" be false would be contradictive.

From this line of reasoning I can see why "a" implies "b" follows. Clearly, the truth of "a" implies the truth of "b" and the falsehood of "b", given truth in "a" would give F (false) for "a→b" as it should.

I can't however see how "b → a" is implied necessarily. Consider "a" being primality for the natural numbers greater than $2$ and "b" being odd-ness of for the set. Clearly for this set of numbers, we will have "a" if and only if we have "b". Indeed if a number is prime, then is also odd. But I don't see why oddness "b", implies "a" (in this case it really doesn't).

I am guessing I am misunderstanding the meaning of "if and only if" semantically. I can't see it as a synonym for equivalence.

Comment: Mathjax can handle logical symbols: `\iff` produces $\iff$ (although `\text{ iff }` works equally well), `\implies` for $\implies$, and `\land` (for **l**ogical **and**) produces $\land$. While you don't use $\lor$ here, it's similar, given by `\lor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"a if and only if b" means
"(a if b) and (a only if b)"

"a if b" means "if b then a."

"a only if b" means a is true only if b is true, so "if a then b."

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So "a if b" strictly means that " "a"must follow from "b" ". My mistake lied in thinking that "iff" does not yield this condition as a necessity. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of "$a$ if and only if (iff) $b$" is simply $a \rightarrow b$ and $b \rightarrow a$. You don't need to interpret the semantics, *iff* is simply an imprecise label (as in, the English language isn't necessarily precise) given to a precise mathematical concept.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I realise what I had in my mind would be more along the lines of $(a \implies b )\land(a\subset b)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left(\begin{array} {cc|c} A & B & A \implies B \\ \hline
T & T & T \\
T & F & F \\
F & T & T \\
F & F & T \\
\end{array}\right)
\land 
\left(\begin{array} {cc|c} A & B & B \implies A\\ \hline
T & T & T\\
T & F & T\\
F & T & F\\
F & F & T\\
\end{array}\right)
=
\left(\begin{array} {cc|c} A & B & (A \implies B) \land (B \implies A) \\ \hline
T & T & T\\
T & F & F\\
F & T & F\\
F & F & T\\
\end{array}\right)$$

Compare with:

$$\begin{array} {cc|c} A & B & A \iff B \\ \hline
T & T & T\\
T & F & F\\
F & T & F\\
F & F & T\\
\end{array}$$

and they are the same.